# How to insert zero in an array at that index, which is exceeding the size of that array?

Tags: python, list, numpy, loops, indexing

I want to insert zero at certain locations in an array, but the index position of the location exceeds the size of the array

I wanted that as the numbers get inserted one by one,  size also gets increased in that process (of the array X), so till it reaches index 62, it will not produce that error.

```
import numpy as np

X = np.arange(0,57,1)

desired_location = [ 0,  1, 24, 25, 26, 27, 62, 63]

for i in desired_location:
    X_new = np.insert(X,i,0)
print(X_new)
```

output

```
File "D:\python programming\random python files\untitled4.py", line 15, in <module>
    X_new = np.insert(X,i,0)

  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in insert

  File "D:\spyder\pkgs\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 4560, in insert
    "size %i" % (obj, axis, N))

IndexError: index 62 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 57
```

Comment: And what do you expect that to do?  If a list has 10 elements and you try to insert at index 25, what do you think should happen?

Comment: @TimRoberts, sir I wanted that as the numbers get inserted one by one its size also gets increased in that process, so till it reaches index `62`, it will not produce that error.

Comment: I think the problem is `desired_location[i]` instead it should be `i` itself. `i` is not an index in `desired_location`.

Comment: You need to read @Mehdi's answer.  You are making a new array each time, but you're not USING that array.  You're starting with `X` every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a copy of `X` into `X_new` so the array gets longer in loop as you desire.

```
X_new = X.copy()
for i in desired_location:
    X_new = np.insert(X_new, i, 0)
```

Comment: The copy is not really necessary.  `X_new = X` is sufficient, because each insert will make a new copy.

Comment: true. I am just being a bit conservative. I thought maybe there is a reason behind making a new copy at all. the original code could be `X = np.insert(X, i, 0)`

Answer (score 1):

how silly I was.

```
import numpy as np

X = np.arange(0,57,1)

desired_location = [ 0,  1, 24, 25, 26, 27, 62, 63]



for i in desired_location:
    X = np.insert(X,i,0)
    
print(X)
```

Comment: Yes, but you should give the credit to @Mehdi for pointing out the issue.

Comment: You could do all inserts at once: `np.insert(X,desired_location-np.arange(8),0)`.

Comment: @timroberts yes sir, of course!

Answer (score 0):

Converting `tolist()`, inserting and converting to `np.array` is an order of magnitude faster.

```
# %%timeit 10000 loops, best of 5: 117 µs per loop
X_new = X
for i in desired_location:
    X_new = np.insert(X_new,i,0)
```

```
# %%timeit 100000 loops, best of 5: 4.18 µs per loop
X_new = X.tolist()
for i in desired_location:
    X_new.insert(i, 0)
np.fromiter(X_new, dtype=X.dtype)
```